# In NestJs is it possible to enable CORS for individual routes?

Tags: cors, nestjs

I know it is possible to enable CORS for the whole app using `app.enableCors`.  But is it possible to enable it for specific routes ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a little pseudo code but looking at the nest.js documentation, this should work.

Enable a default cors config for the app:

```typescript
  // Main app starting point
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './AppModule';

const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.enableCors(); //Enable default cors config for the whole service 
await app.listen(3000);
```

Then in whatever module you want (this example is the main app module but it could be any module in your app) specify a custom cors config for any routes you want:

```typescript
// AppModule.ts
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common';
import cors from 'cors'; 
import { NotesController } from './NotesController';

const customNotesCorsConfig = cors({ /* your custom options here */ });
@Module({controllers: [NotesController]})
  export class AppModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
      consumer
        .apply(customNotesCorsConfig)
            //This one route will have its cors config overriden with the custom implementation
        .forRoutes({ path: 'notes', method: RequestMethod.POST });
    }
}
```

Your controller will have different cors configured for different routes:

```ts
//NotesController.ts
import { Controller, Get, Post } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('notes')
export class NotesController {

    // This route will use the default cors config in the app
    @Get()
    findAll(): string {
        return 'This action returns all notes';
    }

    //This route will use the custom cors config defined in the AppModule file
    @Post()
    create(): string {
        return 'This action creates a new note';
    }
}
```

Be sure to checkout the middleware docs, this shows how route specific overrides can be applied: https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will look into it.